# Удалить строку при помощи регулярных выражений

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$string = '<?php $a=chr(104).chr(101).chr(97).chr(100).chr(101).chr(114);$b= .chr(105).chr(112).chr(116).chr(62);}?><?php echo("dfdsf"); ?>';
$pattern = '/\<\?php %[a-zA-Z0-9_-]%\}\?\>/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $string);
```

пытаюсь вырезать `<?php $a=chr(104).chr(101).chr(97).chr(100).chr(101).chr(114);$b= .chr(105).chr(112).chr(116).chr(62);}?>` из строки `$string`. Но не получается составить регулярное выражение.
предполагаю, что начало строки всегда `<?php $a=` а конец `;}?>` . Между ними могут быть абсолютно любые символы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно для данного случая, регулярное выражение и код будут такими:

```php
$string = '<?php $a=chr(104).chr(101).chr(97).chr(100).chr(101).chr(114);$b= .chr(105).chr(112).chr(116).chr(62);}?><?php echo("dfdsf"); ?>';
$pattern = '/\<\?php[\s\S]+?\?\>/';

echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $string, 1);
```

Рабочий пример на JS:

```js
const string = `<?php \$a=chr(104).chr(101).chr(97).chr(100).chr(101).chr(114);\$b= .chr(105).chr(112).chr(116).chr(62);}?><?php echo("dfdsf"); ?>`;
const pattern = /\<\?php[\s\S]+?\?\>/;

console.log(string.replace(pattern, ''));
```